# alternate ways of formatting a dictionary using a for-loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

So I was looking up how to print this dictionary, `dictionary = {'hello':'1', 'world' : '2'}`  into the terminal/console like this:

> hello : 1
>
> world : 2

One approach was to simply run a for loop:

```
for i in dictionary:
    print(i + ' ' + ":" + " " + dictionary[i])
```

and that worked just fine, however, Is there another way of doing this? I don't understand how the loop knows that `i` is the key and `dictionary[i]` is the value... If someone could explain how it works or give a better method of printing out what I wanted in the blockquote above that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's OK way to do that, `for i in dictionary` will loop over your dict keys that is 'hello' and 'world' so `i` will be your key and `dictionary[i]` will be value corresponding to that key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution, when you do this: `for i in dictionary:` is the same as: `for i in dictionary.keys():`, that is, by default the loop traverses the *keys* in the dictionary. Having said that, I believe this is more idiomatic:

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    print("{} : {}".format(key, value))
```

- We retrieve both the keys and the values at the same time with the `items()` method.
- String formatting is done with the `format()` method, and the `{}` are placeholders to be replaced by the passed arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `dictionary.items()` which returns a list of tupels (key, value). You can than write a for loop like:

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
     # do something
```

There also ways to only get the values or keys to iterate over, this is accomplished via `dictionary.values()` and `dictionary.keys()`.

What you for loop does is iterating over the keys and your `dictionary[i]` is just the regular “get corresponding value for key i ” call.